# How to create file in different directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a file, but in different directory. For example, when my app is in `/home/app1` I would like to create a file in `/home/logs`

I was trying something like this:

```
    json_file = "%s.json" % json_name
    json_file_path = pathlib.Path("%s/%s" % (path, json_file))

    if not json_file_path.is_file():

        file = open(json_file_path, 'w+')
        file.close()
    else:
        print("NotMkay")
```

Where path is `/home/logs`, json_file is filename "example.json" and json_file_path is path + json_file

But all I'm getting is:

```
TypeError: invalid file: PosixPath
```

Comment: What is `path`? What is `json_name`? What is the rest of the stack trace for your error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    file = open(json_file_path, 'w+')
```

I don't think you can pass a `Path` object as an argument to `open`. Instead, try

```
    file = json_file_path.open('w+')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use os.path.join for joining path and os.path exists for checking. String formatting is not safe way.
Working example

```
import os.path
json_file = "%s.json" % 'tst.json'
json_file_path = os.path.join('~', json_file)
print(os.path.exists(json_file_path))
```

This will print 'False'.
For creating dirtree you can use:

```
os.makedirs(json_file_path)
```